# jQuery , jscrollpane - preventing the window from scrolling when reaching end of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jscrollpane

I'm trying to prevent the browser window to scroll if I've reached the top or bottom of my jscrollpane div. [Tinyscrollbar](http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) does that.

with [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) I can detect the div scrolling with something like that:

```
var jsp = $(".scroll-pane").data('jsp'); // getting hold of the api
jsp = $("#" + e.attr('id') + " > .feed-items").bind(
    'jsp-scroll-y', function(e, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
        // reached bottom
        if (jsp.getPercentScrolledY() == 1) {
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    })
```

I tried using `e.preventDefault()` and it didn't work. I tried everything in my magic box, from returning false to stopping propagation. Nothing works. There was this nice hack:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden")
         .css('margin-left', "-" + __scrollbarWidth + "px");
```

But I don't want to use this as it's not perfect.

Any ideas?

Comment: `return false;` should work, as far as i know.

Comment: i would also like to know

Comment: I found the solution in here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5350123/998318

Answer (score 2):

- You must add for example class **test** to the div
- add some javascript:

  ```
   $(document).on('mousewheel', '.test',
        function (e) {
        var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        this.scrollTop += (delta < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 30;
        e.preventDefault();
   });
  ```

its for vertical scroll. if you want to do same for horizontal scroll let me know

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why its working but when you reach bottom or top on mouse scroll wheel its stop scrolling ;)

```
/* Stop scrolling */
$('#cnct_form').bind('jsp-scroll-y',function(event, isScrollable)   {
      console.log('asd');
}).jScrollPane();

$('#cnct_form').mousewheel(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```